# visualCaptcha error on loading

Tags: captcha

I can't figure out what else I need to do to initialize visualcaptcha. Running nginx on local server. I'm getting this error in my error log:

```
2014/11/20 09:00:16 [error] 3567#0: *13 open() "/home/jeff/public/project.com/public/start/6" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /start/6?r=57nri4gpbu HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

I'm using php backend with jquery frontend. I've installed everything in the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff.

Looking at the error it seems you don't have the php server running in the right place, or accepting connections properly.

It seems your static server (which looks for files in `/public/*`) is trying to show `start/6`, when that should be hitting `app.php` or `index.php` (not sure if you are running the demo or coding something yourself).

I'll need more details as to your current file structure and virtualhost/server config in order to help you spot where the error is.

Comment: I got it to where I don't get the error anymore, but it just freezes up on the visualcaptcha call whether it's jquery or straight javascript.

Comment: I thought all I had to do was install the frontend, install the backend, link to the front-end in my html page and make the javascript call. I know my php is working because I have php index page with dynamic content that works fine. I was just wondering if there is a common mistake people make. I probably just need to read up further.

Comment: It should be enough, but it seems there's something else. I'm glad to help if you can provide more details like I asked above, like any console error or server error.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've got these visualcaptcha folders in my root directory:visualCaptcha-frontend-core-master, visualCaptcha-frontend-jquery-master, visualCaptcha-PHP-master. In my virtualhost/server config (nginx) I didn't do anything for visualcaptcha, it's just the standard nginx server block, with a php location for php. And I have a reference in my html to both visualcaptcha.js and visualcaptcha.jquery.js from the visualCaptcha-frontend-core-master. Do I need to ref. visualcaptcha.jquery.js from both the visualCaptcha-frontend-core-master AND the visualCaptcha-frontend-jquery-master folders?

Comment: the only error I was getting that I know of was the above. But I realised that I don't know what visualcaptcha.jquery.js to reference to. When I reference the one in visualCaptcha-frontend-jquery-master I get the error above. When I reference the one in visualCaptcha-frontend-core-master it freezes. So I assume that I should reference the one in visualCaptcha-frontend-jquery-master and figure out why I'm getting the error.

Comment: You don't need the `frontend-core-master` if you're not developing for visualCaptcha's front-end packages.

`PHP-master` is a complete sample that uses the composer and jquery versions, so you won't also need `frontend-jquery-master`.

For the PHP side of it, you need a vhost entry to make sure `http://.../start/6` points to the slim's `app.php`.

This is assuming you ran `composer install` for the PHP repo.

If this all reveals a bit too complicated, there's a simplified version at https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-PHP/tree/v4.2.0 which is "plug-and-play". Nothing to setup.

Comment: The PHP repo was installed with composer. There's an app.php file in visualCaptcha-PHP-master/app/ and that's the only place. So now I'm trying to figure out how to redirect to it through nginx with, I presume, a GET request using "start/6". And I need to configure the image and audio routes this way also I presume. does this seem right? Thanks for extensive assistance.

Comment: I said `app.php` but I meant `index.php`, sorry.

Here's the nginx config I've got for the PHP demo: https://gist.github.com/BrunoBernardino/27ebc5da5f02fc14b0d6

Comment: Thanks for all the help and the nginx config. I'm going to work on this a little more. I must need to gain a little more understanding of "creating custom routes" (from github). I'm trying to implement visualcaptcha into a signup form on a website that I'm creating. You've probably answered my question already and I just don't know it.

Comment: Feel free to ask any more questions. Once you figure out the answer, update your question and mark this as answered :)